# How to @AttributeOverride of column names using xml configuration instead of JPA Anotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to override column names in by subclass using xml.
i know this can be done using @AttributeOverride JPA Anotations but want to achieve the same using XML Configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the embedded and attribute-override elements.

See [Chapter 3. Overriding metadata through XML/3.1.3. Property level metadata](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html#d0e3768).

An example from this document:

```
<attributes>
    <id name="id">
        <column name="fld_id"/>
        <generated-value generator="generator" strategy="SEQUENCE"/>
        <temporal>DATE</temporal>
        <sequence-generator name="generator" sequence-name="seq"/>
    </id>
    <version name="version"/>
    <embedded name="embeddedObject">
        <attribute-override name"subproperty">
            <column name="my_column"/>
        </attribute-override>
    </embedded>
    <basic name="status" optional="false">
        <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
    </basic>
    <basic name="serial" optional="true">
        <column name="serialbytes"/>
        <lob/>
    </basic>
    <basic name="terminusTime" fetch="LAZY">
        <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
    </basic>
</attributes>
```